# SQL Insert with sub-select and multiple rows

Tags: mysql, insert, subquery

I have an existing documents table and a new permissions table. I want to create a script that will give all permissions to all of the existing documents. The documents_permissions table will need the document_id and permission_id (1,2,3). So for each document I will need to insert 3 rows. This is where I am at atm:

```
INSERT INTO `documents_permissions` (`document_id`, `permission_id`)
SELECT `id`, '1' FROM `documents`
```

but I'd need to repeat that for each permission. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

USe **CROSS JOIN**

```
INSERT INTO `documents_permissions` (`document_id`, `permission_id`)
select  `id`,a.permissions
 from(
select 1 as permissions union all
select 2 union all
select 3 )a
cross join
`documents` d
```

Comment: Thanks. So if I wanted to add more permissions would I update it to have `select 3 union all select 4 union all` ?

Comment: You do not need to use UNION ALL unless you have duplicate values like 1,1,2,3,4,4 etc. If you do not have duplicates, UNION keyword is enough

Comment: @Bader: UNION ALL is faster than UNION

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO `documents_permissions` (`document_id`, `permission_id`)
select id, pid from `documents`
cross join (select 1 as pid union select 2 union select 3)X
```